# Redefine malloc/free with static linking has multiple definition error

Tags: c++, c, gcc, malloc, static-linking

Recently, my company wants to update the compiler from gcc-3.4 to gcc-4.5. However, our customer's machine may not have the up-to-date `libstdc++.so`, so we want to static link our binary.

Our program needs customized `malloc()/free()` for very high performance requirement.

I modified the makefile, added a `-static` while linking, and got the following error message:

```
/usr/lib64/libc.a(malloc.o)(.text+0x18c0): In function `free':
: multiple definition of `free'
../../ic/src/memmgr/libmemmgr_mt_thread.a(memmgr_mt_thread.o)(.text+0x3430): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `free' changed from 271 in ../../ic/src/memmgr/libmemmgr_mt_thread.a(memmgr_mt_thread.o) to 255 in /usr/lib64/libc.a(malloc.o)
/usr/lib64/libc.a(malloc.o)(.text+0x3970): In function `malloc':
: multiple definition of `malloc'
../../ic/src/memmgr/libmemmgr_mt_thread.a(memmgr_mt_thread.o)(.text+0x29c0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `malloc' changed from 281 in ../../ic/src/memmgr/libmemmgr_mt_thread.a(memmgr_mt_thread.o) to 461 in /usr/lib64/libc.a(malloc.o)
/usr/lib64/libc.a(malloc.o)(.text+0x4050): In function `realloc':
: multiple definition of `realloc'
../../ic/src/memmgr/libmemmgr_mt_thread.a(memmgr_mt_thread.o)(.text+0x3e80): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `realloc' changed from 335 in ../../ic/src/memmgr/libmemmgr_mt_thread.a(memmgr_mt_thread.o) to 927 in /usr/lib64/libc.a(malloc.o)
```

Ok, it is reasonablle, since `libc.a` already has `malloc()/free()`.

But what confuses me is why there is no error while dynamic linking. I searched, and found this question: [How to redefine malloc() in Linux for use in C++ new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364647). The answer says the linker treats library file(.a) and object file(.o) differently. Now I know the reason why the error happens with static linking but not with dynamic.

However, I tried the solution described in that answer, replaced the library file with the object file directly, but there is no difference. I still got the multiple definition linking error. I also tried `-static-libgcc` (because I don't know what to do, I just tried everything I saw in `gcc` man page) but it does not help, too.

I do not have to use static linking. I just want to solve the `libstdc++.so` version problem. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

edit: Sorry I did not make myself clear. Using `#define malloc ...` may not help here. Since our program is C++. The `#define` idiom can only affact the `malloc()/free()` function. But our program acutally uses `new/delete` to allocate/free memory. Thanks anyway :D

Comment: hi @yoco, did you have a solution in the end with static linking? I go t the same problem.

Comment: @user1147800 I don't have a static link solution. I dynamic link in the end.

Comment: You could statically link `libstdc++.a` and dynamically link `libc.so`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your primary concern is the availability of libstdc++.so in the target system, then why not simply distribute the newer version of that together with your application?

I think that static linking in any case is not a good solution, compiling the project becomes much harder, and if you are using shared objects yourself (for example when using your own plugins), then static linking would simply stop working, since a separate *copy* of the static library would need to be linked into *each* of your binaries, executable and so alike. And can you imagine what happens if there are multiple instances of global variables, locks etc in the same program when it gets loaded? I'll tell you: crashes.

So don't static link, copy libstdc++.so to a private directory (I don't know where your application is installed, but if it has a private prefix, that's quite simple, use $prefix/lib).

Then either set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or use -rpath to encode the path into the binary, so that the linker finds it. Of course, then this means that all libraries that you link against, that could possibly use libstdc++ too, should also be distributed with your app.

But size-wise, it is about the same, with static linking you'd carry that code too.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need to solve my problem. I am really appreciate that you know what I want even I can not express my question well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use dynamic linking with [rpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath_%28linking%29). See "man ld" and "man ld.so".

The $ORIGIN expansion might be useful : bundle every .so you need in the same directory as the program (or a subdirectory) and use "-rpath $ORIGIN" or "-rpath,'$ORIGIN/lib" when linking with ld.

Many programs use this approach to bundle their own private libs.

The other way is to use a .sh script to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and then call the real program (download firefox binary and look at run-mozilla.sh). However the LD_LIBRARY_PATH will leak to subprocesses. So it's not as clean but probably more portable to non GNU systems.

Answer (score 2):

You should use your own free/alloc/realloc function in the project, but i strongly advise you to use the same name as the standard library.

for example

```
void* myProject_malloc(...)
void myProject_free()
```

You can combine it with a macro to redirect the allocation function to your fonction but i dont really adivse you to do it. you are obliged to check if all your source code include this header file, and the compiler can warmed you about macro redefinition (depending on the compiler and on the option you are using)

```
#define malloc(x) myProject_malloc(x)
#define free() myProject_free()
```

If you dont want to use the standard library, you should use the gcc option: "-nostdlib". But if you do this, you can not use any other function of the standard library.

Comment: I do want to use standard library. But only want to replace the malloc/free. I am now reading the GCC document to see if there are answer.

Comment: Then you should define your own malloc function with a different name as I did write, and use a macro to redefine malloc to your own function. You can not call it malloc because you will have two different malloc function implementation the one in your library, and the one in the libc.

Answer (score 1):

Use could use [GNU malloc Hooks](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html) if you are using GNU libc. I'm not so happy with the design of this API so I don't recommend using this.

You can try to patch libc. Remove all the code in `malloc/` and replace it with your implementation.

Using the same idea, you might try to to take `libc.a`, remove all the `.o` files containing `malloc` and friends (this should be mostly all the `.o` files corresponding to `malloc/*.c`) and repack `libc.a` with your implementation.

Comment: Thank you. I had surveyed this solution, too. But using this need some little extra coding work. So the rpath solution is better for me :D

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you'll need to change the names of you custom allocation routines. After that you should use the method described in the answer to save time so you don't have to change all the calls to the new name:

```
#define malloc myMalloc
#define free myFree
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply :D But the #define idiom can not help. I had edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to do it for C++, you can override the new, delete, new[], delete[] operators. See 18.6.1 "Storage allocation and deallocation"

```
  void* operator new(std::size_t size);
  [...]
  void operator delete(void* ptr);
```

"Replaceable: a C++ program may define a function with this function signature that displaces the default version defined by the C++ standard library."

I don"t know if it works with static linking however (don't know how it is implemented).